Dynamic grouping of columns, using groupby
So I have 2 columns in a pandas dataframe, which are float values. I wanted to group the median values of the 2nd column based on the ranges in the first column (used pd.df.groupby). So I started with uniform ranges, such that if the first column's values have a range of 20 to 40, so I group them in bins of size 2 (using np.linspace). But the resulting distribution table is not so informative to me, as the sizes are not distributed uniformly.
My table looks like this, when i use pandas group by and pandas cut: 
Ind     Col1    Col2
0     21.2     4
1     21.8     2
2     27       4
3     27       6
4     38.2     9
5     36.1     1
6     30      1 
7     24.1     10
8     29.5     8
9     31       8
Grouped table:
Group      Median  Range
20-22      3     [2,4]
22-24      NaN     [0]
24-26      10     [10]
26-28      5      [4,6]
28-30      8      [8]
30-32      4.5     [1,8]
32-34      NaN     [0]
34-36      NaN     [0]
36-38      1     [1]
38-40      9     [9]
(A point to note is that the 2 columns are positively correlated, so I expect the medians to increase with the bucket id. The example is pretty random.)
Then I created my own numpy array of ranges, by grouping logarithmically: so if the first column had values between 1 and 10000, my bins are 1 to 10, 10 to 100 and so on. My sizes became much better when I do so. The third issue I am currently facing is that the medians of multiple ranges are the same still. Like multiple bins of ranges have the median 0, which means all the values in these ranges combined were 0 probably. But ideally I'd want all the 3-4 ranges beiong grouped together as a range, and the unequal ranges be subdivided further for detail. Now I know I can hard-code it to check if the medians are same and then not use the set of ranges I'm using at the moment, but it seems too tedious and I feel there must be some function somewhere which does this better, as groupby is a pretty common function.
My goal is to get a distribution which groups the 1st column uniformly, but at the same time the 10 2nd column medians should be in some order and equidistant as per my data. The problem with 3, NaN, 10, 5, 8 etc is the NaN values, and the randomness, which can be resolved if the 1st column was grouped suitably and dynamically.
Are there any such functions you know? Or is there some better algorithm you may suggest?
PS: Please let me know if this isn't the appropriate forum for this question.
I searched the web and this website, but didn't find any such functions. The closes it gets is that we need to group dynamically on the basis of multiple columns/lists of columns etc, but thats not the point.

What you want is not really clear, do you want to form groups of equal size? Have you tried qcut?

Added an edit. Uniform ranges dont represent my data correctly. I dont have an exact way of finding non uniform ranges, such that the second column medians also make sense. I have tried qcut, and while it improves my frequencies, the ranges arent that representative of the first column. Like I wouldn't want ranges such as 20-30, 30-37, 37-38 and 38-40. I prefer 20-28, 28-30,30-32 and 32-40 over the previous case.

@mozway which is why I went for the manual logarithmic technique

To be honest, it looks like you have a rather clear idea of what you want, but this is not obvious at all for others. Please find a way to explain the desired logic, maybe using a graph/schematic or explicit minimal examples with input + output.
